PostgreSQL & SQLAlchemy: Minimizing Impacts of latency with chatty applications
Are there any ways to minimize the impact of latency between the application and database when running PostgreSQL & SQLAlchemy ORM?  Changing loading strategies or preloading properties has been effective - just generally reducing the number of statements between app & database.  Are there any other techniques that can be used to minimize the impact of that connection overhead?
In the below Grafana graphs, I simulated 10ms latency between application and database using the tc traffic control module.  At the midway point, I removed this artificial latency resulting in about 300 microsecond latency when timing SELECT 1; between the application and database (localhost loopback interface - database inside the same container as the application).

This seems to indicate latency sensitivity in the measured process / API endpoints.

A typical way to improve performance over high-latency networks is to use user-defined database functions. That way, you can execute many statements with a single client-server round trip.
One other way to improve the performance over high-latency networks is to use pipelining: you send several statements to the server and don't wait for the result of the previous statement before sending the next one.
There is support for pipelining in the network protocol, and recent PostgreSQL versions have support for that in the C API. You can also do that by sending several statements in a single command, separated by semicolons.
I have no idea if any of the above is supported by your client API and the ORM you are using.

Thanks Laurenz.  I had seen mention of Pipelining in the docs, but did not want to bias the answers - and I don't quite understand how the feature is used yet.  Does Pipeline still support a traditional transaction model where each statement may be dependent on previous results?
"""
While pipeline mode provides a significant performance boost, writing clients using the pipeline mode is more complex because it involves managing a queue of pending queries and finding which result corresponds to which query in the queue.
""" Wondering how this might mesh with a FIFO type ORM functionality

No, pipelining can only be used if statements don't depend on the result of previous statements.

It looks like with Python, the common psycopg3 PostgreSQL driver v3.1 adds Pipeline Mode support. It should be compatible with most versions of PostgreSQL, but was first mentioned in PG14.  As Pipeline Mode is somewhat specific to PostgreSQL it seems it will be a while before ORM like SQLAlchemy also leverage it, except when working with the driver connection directly.  executemany in that driver seems like it may use Pipeline mode without code changes which might be nice. https://blog.dalibo.com/2022/09/19/psycopg-pipeline-mode.html https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/10861
